# How to add a javascript variable to div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have some code that is roughly along the lines of this:

```
exportValue = []; 

function reduceArray() {
    //does something 
    exportValue = parseFloat(exportValue)
}
```

From that, I get that `exportValue` is 73951. I then have to add that number to the page... so I tried both of these:

```
$("#exportValueDiv").append(exportValue);
$("#exportValueDiv").append("<li>" + exportValue + "</li>");
```

But that doesn't work.. I'm confused on how to add something like a variable to the DOM....

If I do something like:

```
$( "#exportValueDiv" ).append( "<li>value</li>")
```

it works, but I don't want to add a string, I want to add the value of the variable. I looked this up, but I'm still confused, so any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: jQuery's append() method (as you're using it) appends an HTML element (identified by a string containing HTML, a wrapped jQuery element or an actual element object), not "text". If you want to simply set the content of your div to the value try $("#exportValueDiv").text(exportValue);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into [jQuery manipulation](https://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/)

```
$("#exportValueDiv").text(exportValue); //Replaces text of #exportValueDiv
$("#exportValueDiv").html('<span>'+exportValue+'</span>'); //Replaces inner html of #exportValueDiv
$("#exportValueDiv").append('<span>'+exportValue+'</span>'); //Adds to the inner html of #exportValueDiv
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! But I figured out my error was due to an unfinished `AJAX` call

Answer (score 2):

The [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) contract expects a DOM element or HTML String. You will need to do:

```
$("#exportValueDiv").append("<div>" + exportValue + "</div>");
```

Comment: He spent the time to link to documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#exportValueDiv").append("<div>" + exportValue + "</div>");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

The following appends your variable to a div that already has information:

```
<div id="exportValueDiv">
<p>
Some information.
</p>
</div>

<script>
var exportValue = "Hello world.";
$("#exportValueDiv").append('<p>'+ exportValue +'</p>');
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/supadave57/f9tqw0d4/

Comment: Thanks for the answer!!